# How display preformatted text in a pdf generated by fop?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Does anyone know how I can display preformatted html text like:

```
<ol>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ol>
```

inside a pdf generated with fop?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the `<ol>` code as plain text or do you actually want an unordered list with 3 list items?

Comment: I actually want an unordered list with 3 list items

Answer (score 3):

This XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ol">
    <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="24pt" space-before=".1in" space-after=".1in">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:list-block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
        <fo:block><xsl:number format="1."/></fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-label>
      <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input will produce the following XSL-FO:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="24pt" space-before=".1in" space-after=".1in">
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block>1.</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block>item 1</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block>2.</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block>item 2</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item>
               <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block>3.</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-label>
               <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block>item 3</fo:block>
               </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
         </fo:list-block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

which will produce a PDF that contains the following (tested with FOP 1.0):

[image]

Comment: Hey.Can you post any blog where we can have detail understanding of the tags used.

Comment: @DhirajGandhi - Take a look at the free book [Practical Formatting Using XSL-FO](http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/training/) (please consider donating if it helps; I have no connection to Crane Softwrights). Also take a look at [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/).

Answer (score 2):

**[Use the attributes `linefeed-treatment="preserve"` and `white-space-collapse="false"`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#fo-preformat)**

Either escape the HTML:

```
<block linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false">
     &lt;ol>
      &lt;li>item 1&lt;/li>
      &lt;li>item 2&lt;/li>
      &lt;li>item 3&lt;/li>
    &lt;/ol>
</block>
```

Or use CDATA:

```
<block linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false">  
   <![CDATA[
    <ol>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
    ]]>
</block>
```

Comment: With these attributes still, i am not able to the HTML tags escaped. It shows <ol>....</ol> on the PDF. Help please