# Can't render HTML text in pdf generated by apache fop

Tags: apache, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I am trying to generate PDF with Apache fop an ran into one problem. I have some labels that are `Map<String, String> labels` in our data object. I marshal this data object and provide it to apache fop. Everything works more or less fine but sometime labels can contain text that has   tags. What I want is to display text in pdf without  tags so instead of "`This is <b>important</b>`" it would display "This is **important**"

I am displaying my content like

```
 <fo:block>   <xsl:value-of 
 select="/documentx/labels[key='important']/value" 
 disable-output-escaping="yes"/> </fo:block>
```

However it is displayed like simple text with `<b>` so I can not apply any template since it is not matched with b tag.

Tried solution below but it didn't work so would be very thankful for any help and suggestions.

[How display preformatted text in a pdf generated by fop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125899/how-display-preformatted-text-in-a-pdf-generated-by-fop)

Comment: The linked solution should work. Did you create a `template match="b"` to define that the text must be rendered as bold? Can you show the relevant section of your template?

Comment: @Hobbes yes I created template match="b" . If I create lets say String myTag = "some <b>value</b>", then i can match tag with  template match="myTag" in fo file. However  template match="b" doesnt work. Could it be that content of myTag is wrapped into CDATA internaly hence <b> is not parsed since it is part of CDATA data. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to unwrap the CDATA elements first. Do an XSLT transformation to unwrap the CDATA, then a separate XSLFO transformation.

Comment: @Hobbes Hmm how to unwrap CDATA elements? Any link would help